# how to dismiss action sheet with a custom button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiactionsheet

I created two buttons and one date picker on the action sheet.On clicking the done button i want to dismiss the action sheet.Can anyone please help with the code for dismissing the action sheet.

i'm using this code for giving action for done button:

```
[doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in dismissActionSheet method write

```
[aSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: ,"buttonIndex:"  will not work in this case i think.i'm searching for a code just like we dismiss the view controller.

Answer (score 3):

Implement the delegate `<UIActionSheetDelegate>`. and paste the following code in button click event.

```
[actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep an instance variable that points to your actionSheet and than in your `dismissActionSheet:` function just write `[actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];`. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the [UIActionSheetdelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIActionSheetDelegate) protocol and you will be good to go. Specifically `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` .

Comment: is there any other method for dismissing the action sheet.because i created the buttons through code.

Comment: Yeah it will be dismissed automatically. Check the documentation. Just implement the delegate.